# Как понизить производительность видеокарты nvidia до минимума на linux?

Tags: linux, nvidia

Я хотел бы чтобы видеокарта просто работала на мощности, необходимой лишь для отрисовки базовой картинки и может быть просмотра видео. Игры мне не нужны. В адаптивном режиме уровень мощности постоянно скачет от 0 до максимума и время от времени просто так создаёт жару в комнате. Есть ли способ как-то настроить карту, чтобы мощность всегда была 0 и кулер не стеснялся опускать температуру до 50 градусов и ниже?

Comment: а может причина в пыли и засохшей термопасте?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, я имею ввиду, что температура повышается в вполне предсказуемые моменты. Например, если запустить игру, она точно поднимется. При выходе из игры опустится. Но для меня пусть лучше эта игра тормозит, чем создаёт лишнюю жару и шум.

Comment: настраивайте тротлинг. Но как мне кажется, проще поставить пару больших кулеров, почистить старые и результат не заставит себя ждать

Comment: @KoVadim жара-то в комнате всё равно будет создаваться, при +35°C не очень хотелось бы)

Comment: @KoVadim [вот такую картину](https://imgur.com/0WDKVpd.png) я обычно вижу при простое. Вроде бы и не критическая температура, но slowdown temp 191C это что-то ненормальное и кулер никогда не вращается на полную мощность даже в играх. Как это всё настраивать я не представляю, потому и спрашиваю. Там в настройках есть режим "максимальная производительность", но мне нужен ровно противоположный.